# Friend Class of child try to access protected function of Parent

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inheritance, gcc, friend

I've got a **Parent** Class and a **Child** Class. The Parent have a protected function called **setId(int id)**. Now I want to make the setId function acessable by friend class of **Child** (lets call it **Friend**). Is this possible or do I have to reimplement the setId function inside the Child class and use the protected setId function of parent?

I've tried this with VS-Compiler and it works.

I use gcc and get "error: ‘void Parent::setId(int)’ is protected"

Class Parent

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(){}

protected:
    void setId(int id){m_id=i}

    int m_id;
};
```

Class Child

```
#include "Parent.h"

class Child
        : public Parent
{
    friend class FriendClass;
public:
    Child(){}
};
```

Class Friend

```
#include "Child.h"

class FriendClass
{
public:
    FriendClass(){
      Child c;
      c.setId(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of describing the code, please *show* it to us. Preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i was still wrining, sorry. Now the code is online ;)

Comment: Who is ManInTheMiddle?

Comment: Opps :) If change it

Comment: [No repro](https://ideone.com/xKeiHu). Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common wisdom holds that the right way is to upgrade access in Child:

```
class Child: public Parent {
public:
    void setId(int id) override { Parent::setId(id); } // public for Friend
};
```

The usual rationale is that this is brief and expresses clearly and precisely what's being made public, without publishing any other internals.